# Making a plugin file accessible via url rewrite?

Tags: plugin-development, redirect, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

In my WordPress plugin I have a php file that generates some stats about the blog and outputs it as a simple text file. To access WordPress functions I've included this at the top of the file:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-blog-header.php');
```

Now I'd like to hide the actual URL, since it's in the wp-content/plugins directory and replace it with something nice and short:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/plugin/data-fetcher/list-data.php

-> rewrite to http://example.com/list-data
```

I added this to `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^list-data$ wp-content/plugins/data-fetcher/list-data.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem: when I access the short URL, I get a 301 Moved Permanently redirect before I end up on the page. This means that the wp-content/plugins/... URL is revealed in the browser.

I suspect that WordPress is initiating this somehow. The rewrite rule works fine for images and plain php files (i.e. without WP includes/require).

Is my assumption correct? How can I prevent WordPress from sending the redirect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark,

I hate to say it, but you're going about this the wrong way.  PHP files in your plug-in should *never* be accessed directly in this way.  Instead, they should be loaded from within WordPress just like everything else.

Here are some alternative paths you could take:

**Create an admin page that displays your stats**

This is a page accessible from within WordPress by authenticated users only.  If you use the correct API, this page will look very clean and will display your simple stats however you want.  Since it's inside WordPress to begin with, you'll already have access to the entire WP API without needing to load `wp-blog-header.php` directly.

**Use your existing system, but register the rewrite with WordPress**

You should never modify your `.htaccess` file directly.  This file can be changed when you add new plug-ins or change your permalink structure, meaning you'll lose your customizations.  Instead, you can create a custom rewrite by making a function call within WordPress itself:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite' );
function my_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    add_rewrite_rule('list-data/$', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/data-fetcher/list-data.php', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);  // This should really be done in a plugin activation
}
```

This will add your custom rule to the top of the WordPress rewrite rules and should skip any other redirects WordPress matches against the regex.

For a great example of how you can implement this kind of simple rewriting in a plug-in, check out Ozh's tutorial on redirecting a pretty login URL:

- [Pretty Login URL: a Simple Rewrite API Plugin Example](http://planetozh.com/blog/2011/01/pretty-login-url-a-simple-rewrite-api-plugin-example/)

Comment: If you're going to update `.htaccess`, shouldn't that be a hard flush (and pass `true` as a parameter)? And `$wp_rewrite` is a global variable. Of course, if you do this only once (not for a plugin that should be distributed), you can also leave out the `flush_rules()` line and just visit the *Permalinks* page, which will flush your rules anyway.

Comment: Right and right ... updated accordingly.  The only reason I add `flush_rules()` here is so that adding the rule is a one-step process (i.e. you activate the plug-in) rather than activating it and then pushing the change by going to another page.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know if it works. My WP install is in a subdirectory /wordpress/. Will the redirect start with /wp-contents anyway?

Comment: You'll have to give it a try and see.  But the re-written URL is meant to be relative to the WordPress installation.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the example. That did the trick for me. One additional catch: first I had this pattern: "^list-data$", but it turns out that it has to be "list-data$".

Comment: Downvoted because this method doesn't account for WP_CONTENT_DIR or WP_PLUGIN_URL and should only be used for core files, such as `wp-login.php`.

Comment: @scribu Rather than just downvoting, I'd really like you to maybe edit the original answer to account for those constants or add your own answer instead.

Comment: @scribu I've updated the method to use `WP_PLUGIN_URL`.

Comment: Using WP_PLUGIN_URL directly in there probably doesn't work, since it's supposed to be relative to the wp root dir. If it were that easy, yes, I would have just updated the answer myself.

Comment: As with any answer on a StackExchange site, it's meant to be a starting point ... not a complete solution.  It works well enough in test environments, and there are other ways to do it.

Comment: The "Pretty Login" example link is broken - now pointing to a domain hosting malware. The correct link should be http://planetozh.com/blog/2011/01/pretty-login-url-a-simple-rewrite-api-plugin-example/

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, but there was no malware at the previous URL. Just a false positive on Ozh's URL shortener ...

Answer (score 10):

You can also set a custom variable inside WordPress when your URL is accessed. You can then later check for this variable and if it exists, do whatever you want to do.

In this example, we will use `wpse6891_stats` as our variable.

```
// Register a URL that will set this variable to true
add_action( 'init', 'wpse6891_init' );
function wpse6891_init() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^stats$', 'index.php?wpse6891_stats=true', 'top' );
}

// But WordPress has a whitelist of variables it allows, so we must put it on that list
add_action( 'query_vars', 'wpse6891_query_vars' );
function wpse6891_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'wpse6891_stats';
    return $query_vars;
}

// If this is done, we can access it later
// This example checks very early in the process:
// if the variable is set, we include our page and stop execution after it
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse6891_parse_request' );
function wpse6891_parse_request( &$wp )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'wpse6891_stats', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/stats.php' );
        exit();
    }
}
```

You can also do the check later, with `get_query_var( 'wpse6891_stats' )`.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: You mean to say that we have to write this in functions.php in our themes folder? can you help me as to where do i write this code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @noobcode: If you use this in a theme, you place it in `functions.php`. If you use it in a plugin, you place it in the plugin code.