# Need to make a php file inside theme accessible via url

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I checked this post here [Making a plugin file accessible via url rewrite?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/making-a-plugin-file-accessible-via-url-rewrite) which seems to have the same problem as me but its for a plugin. But so far i am getting 404.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite' );
function my_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    add_rewrite_rule('/$', '/wp-content/themes/econ/adserver/adserver.js.php', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);  
}
```

I have this file path `/wp-content/themes/econ/adserver/adserver.js.php` and need to show it as `http://mysite.com/adserver.js.php`

**UPDATE:**

The code that **Bainternet** gave is working good except the rewrite rule part. I can now access the file using `index.php?myjs=true`. Here is the code in my htaccess file you might wanna take a look.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: using `/$` is bad news, change to something like `js/$` and your url to `mysite.com/js/adserver.js.php`

Comment: @Bainternet yes also tried `/adserver$` to have something like `mysite.com/adserver/adserver.js.php` but did not worked either.

Comment: If the resultant code is *javascript*, why not simply enqueue it as javascript, where appropriate?

Comment: @Chip Bennett : Some get variable will send via the php file that will change the javascript file and also the url will be called from external sites. It is an ad rotating script.

Comment: @Sisir the first one shouldn't be a problem. A javascript `<script>` can be completely encapsulated by a PHP `function some_script() {}` call, allowing you to pass PHP variables to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is a test working solution:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: wpse26719
Plugin URI: http://en.bainternet.info
Description: Need to make a php file inside theme accessible via url
Version: 1.0
Author: Bainternet
Author URI: http://en.bainternet.info
*/

// Register a URL that will set this variable to true
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'wpse26719_rw');
function wpse26719_rw($wp_rewrite) {
   $newrules = array();
   $new_rules['^adserver.js.php$'] = 'index.php?myjs=true';
   $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}


// Add myjs as a query var
add_action( 'query_vars', 'wpse26719_query_vars' );
function wpse26719_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'myjs';
    return $query_vars;
}

// If this is done, we can access it later
// This example checks very early in the process:
// if the variable is set, we include our page and stop execution after it
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse26719_parse_request' );
function wpse26719_parse_request( &$wp )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'myjs', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/adserver.js.php' );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: what should i do with it? Paste it into `functions.php`? do i need to change the line `include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/adserver.js.php' );` to `include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/adserver/adserver.js.php' );` as that file is inside the directory `adserver`?

Comment: ok. I have placed the file in the theme root directory. using you same code in the `functions.php` file and trying to access the file with the url `http://mysite.com/adserver.js' still getting `404` error. But your part of the code is working check http://beta.econengine.com/index.php?myjs=true we can access the script like this. Still need the rewrite think working. :)

Comment: The rewrite is working on my end, try flushing your rewrite rules, simply go to your settings>>permalinks and save.

Comment: interesting! it looks like wordpress functions are not defined in that php file? what gives? check this url http://beta.econengine.com/adserver.js.php?id=500

Comment: that's because you are bypassing WordPress with the rewrite rules.

Comment: That kinda brake down the whole idea here. As i need to query for posts in that php file. I wanted to bypassing the wp rewrite rules not the wp engine :(

Comment: Don't know what happened. but suddenly the wp functions are started working inside that script. I think i still don't understand lots of thing.. feeling like a dumb!! :(

Answer (score 3):

WP rewrite rules are not real rewrites nor will they allow redirects like that. So you can't use them that way. Fortunately, WP should have you covered there even if you try.

See, an internal WordPress rewrite rule must change a URL pattern into an index.php?key=value pattern.

So when you use add_rewrite_rule to insert a rule that doesn't point to the index.php file, then this should get detected and a "hard" rule will be created in the .htaccess file for it. Thus, check the .htaccess file after doing the hard flush and see if your new rule exists there as a normal RewriteRule. If not, then maybe the .htaccess isn't writable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite' );
function my_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    add_rewrite_rule('^adserver.js.php$', '/wp-content/themes/econ/adserver/adserver.js.php', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);  
}
```

And you should probably remove $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true); once you have it working, since that's a big performance hit on every page view.

Comment: Sorry man! not working :(

Comment: Are "pretty" permalinks working on your site? Can you paste the contents of your .htaccess file?