# How-to add rewrite rules to point the uploads folder to a subdomain

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mobile, responsive

### The goal

Point the upload-folder to a static subdomain to serve [adaptive images](http://adaptive-images.com/), that can get cached.

#### WordPress Rewrite Rules

You can read more in detail about [rewrite rules API](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api) at Christopher Davis site.

#### The how-to on adaptive-images.php

Those are the steps needed (*just to make the Q complete*):

> 1. The HTML starts to load in the browser and a snippet of JS in the  writes a session cookie, storing the visitor's screen size in pixels.
> 2. The browser then encounters an  tag and sends a request to the server for that image. It also sends the cookie, because that’s how browsers work.
> 3. Apache receives the request for the image and immediately has a look in the website's .htaccess file, to see if there are any special instructions for serving files.
> 4. There are! The .htaccess says "Dear server, any request you get for a JPG, GIF, or PNG file please send to the adaptive-images.php file instead."

The PHP file then does some intelligent thinking which can cover a number of scenario's but I'll illustrate one path that can happen:

> 1. The PHP file looks for a cookie and finds that the user has a maximum screen size of 480px.
> 2. It compares the cookie value with all $resolution sizes that were configured, and decides which matches best. In this case, an image maxing out at 480px wide.
> 3. It then has a look inside the /ai-cache/480/ folder to see if a rescaled image already exists.
> 4. We'll pretend it doesn’t - the PHP then goes to the actual requested URI to find the original file.
> 5. It checks the image width. If that's smaller than the user's screen width it sends the image.
> 6. If it's larger, the PHP creates a down-scaled copy and saves that into the /ai-cache/480/ folder ready for the next time it's needed. It and also sends it to the user.

#### The question

How would I set up the rewrite rules to point a subdomain to the the uploads folder and vice versa?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the best approach, could you not achieve the desired outcome using the standard css3 approach for responsive design?

Comment: As there's no definitive resolution for mobile devices, I reduced the built in media sizes to one. Now it makes sense to serve them a) from a static domain and b) cache them for the next visitors. If you've a completely better (and faster) approach: Let me know.

Comment: You make a fair point, I'd be interested to see the results, I've posted my answer below .

Comment: would the delay in redirecting cancel out the gains from the cookieless subdomain?

Comment: @DavidXia No and there won't be a real delay. Plus you could download more than two files per time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not willing to filter only image uploads, i.e., all uploaded media will reside in the same folder/subdomain, then there's a simple configuration solution:

- go to options-media.php
- set the *Store uploads* option to `wp-content/uploads`
- set the *Full URL* option to `http://uploads.yourdomain.com`
- create a subdomain making the uploads folder be `http://uploads.yourdomain.com`

Comment: I'll give this a try in some days and report back. Thanks +1.

Comment: cool, as for the mobile sized images, I'd try adding a custom size `add_image_size( 'iphone-images', 480, 0, false );` and then serve the proper size [according to the device](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/) `the_post_thumbnail( 'iphone-images' );`

Comment: For [images sizes, I recommend to look at my Gist here](https://gist.github.com/1853928), which cares about the whole stuff in every detail. Note: If you want to skip a built in size, assign `0` to `h/w`. This way the not wanted image sizes don't get saved. About device sniffing: WP has it built in. You can check with `$is_iphone` if the user's using a mobile device (incl. tabletts). Problem is that they all got the different resolutions und pixel density... :|

Comment: oh, I was not aware of the built in capacity of WP for device sniffing, thx for the tips

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely no expert in htaccess, but with a bit of research I found something that I believe would be a good starting point for what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.+)\.adaptive-images\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ http://www.adaptive-images.com?url=$1.$2 [R,NC,L]
```

The idea of the first line is to prevent adaptive-images.com from getting snagged up in the rule, otherwise it would be a recursive call back to adaptive-images, which I assume you do not want.

Credit goes to [corz.org](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) for this - the page on htaccess is excellent.

Have you considered running a bit of ajax to do what you want instead? Your level of control might be much higher over what you want to control.

Comment: Ehm, not sure if I got you right. Adaptive Images is not a service. It runs on my own server.

Comment: I saw that you linked to it in your question.  The principle is the same - just change the domain name(s) in the rewrite rules.

Comment: As I thought that this topic will maybe be interesting for later readers too, I awarded a bounty and expected to see the full code here. It's _imho_ clear that the answer that gets the bounty awarded should have some WP related code. Else it could be moved to SO as well.

Answer (score 0):

The techniqe you're looking for is [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

Either of the following should acheive what you want, steps 1 and 2 are irrelevant to the answer this simply redirects any request for a file ending in .jpg, .gif or .png to the php file.

```
RedirectMatch \.(png|gif|jpg)$ http://example.com/cache.php
```

Or using RewriteRule:-

```
RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpg)$ cache.php [L]
```

Comment: With "rewrite" rule, I meant the built in WP rewrite rules - see the Update/Link to Christopher Davis. :) If it wouldn't be that way, the Q would be _off topic_ and moved to SO.

Comment: Oh I see, well it's precisely the same principle, you just need to find a string that matches and perform the action - it really is an SO question and I can't see any advantage to doing php over htaccess - as I understand it htaccess and php run in the same process space.

Comment: @kaiser I like the `.htaccess` approach and I don't think it's off-topic. You can make a plugin or theme to write these rules into `.htaccess `for you. See: [insert_with_markers()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L53) or http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36233/how-to-add-htaccess-code-through-a-function/36237#36237

Comment: Want to write an answer?

Comment: As I thought that this topic will maybe be interesting for later readers too, I awarded a bounty and expected to see the full code here. It's _imho_ clear that the answer that gets the bounty awarded should have some WP related code. Else it could be moved to SO as well.

Comment: @kaiser the wordpress rewrite rules are for manipulating URLs with variables in them - there isn't wordpress code that would work for your question.