# Rewrites: .htaccess or wp_rewrite for bulk 301 changes?

Tags: url-rewriting, wp-redirect

I'm migrating a site from an older CMS to WordPress. We'll be on the same domain but about 90-100 pages are going to have modified URLs - so, for them, I'm creating 301 Rewrite rules.

My question is: am I better to include these rewrites in the `.htaccess` file for the site or `wp_rewrite`?

As I understand it, I should do this in `.htaccess` because `wp_rewrite` is generally intended for creating patterns rather than bulk rewrites.

That said, if `wp_rewrite` was a good method, it would be preferable in my case because I could keep the rewrites in the `functions.php` file so users without root access could edit them.

Some of the rules will contain regex, but not all. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(http://.*)/en/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

(I'd prefer not to use a plugin for this, though "Redirection" is a great tool.)

Comment: Consider Safe Redirect Manager https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/

Comment: Thanks @vancoder - but I don't want to use a plugin for this.

Comment: .htaccess is the way to go, anything handled dynamically within WordPress requires spinning everything up just to redirect somewhere else and do it all over again. [have a look at this answer for a start](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36239/4771).

Comment: Thanks, @Milo - that works great. I used the code you suggested [above](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36239/4771) in functions.php and it's rewriting to .htaccess now. However, I'm wondering, isn't it very inefficient to run this every page load? Is there a conditional wrap to call the function that you'd recommend? Thanks!